# chrome extension development close openned window from javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

When developing a chrome extension I managed to open a new tab by using this code in my javascript file

```
myWindow=window.open("www.google.com");
```

I could close it immediately after opening it with:

```
myWindow.close();
```

I tried several methods for javascript for it to wait some seconds before closing but if I do that it doesn't close. Maybe it's because it loses the window's id? I don't know. I just started learning about chrome extension development.

[EDIT] I am submitting all of the code I have to help you guys. I remind you that I am trying to develop a chrome extension and the action happens when I click on the button on my toolbar created by my extension. (Code taken from here: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html)

HTML FILE

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
<style>
  body {
    min-width: 357px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }

  img {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
  }
  </style>
 <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

MANIFEST

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "myExtension",
"description": "This extension is under development",
"version": "1.0",

"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": ["www.google.com"]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `setInterval`?

Comment: @Jacedc Yes, I have tried that. It seems that it doesn't care about what's coming next because it opens a new tab. Am I right about this?

Comment: It might be something else in your code, as this works: http://jsfiddle.net/bCnH3/

Comment: @Markasoftware This is for a chrome extension. I don't know if something in the manifest or in the html file prevent this. I'm new to this and I thought that javascript would work as normal [EDIT] That is all my code in the js file.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be doing this from the extension's popup. Popups are closed when they loose focus, so my guess is that what's happening is that its execution environment is being destroyed when your new window gets the focus. So any delayed event you set up there can't be executed.

It seems your popup is an empty window and the only thing it does is opening the window. In that case you don't need to define a popup. You can do that from a background page using the [`chrome.browserAction.onClicked` event](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#event-onClicked).

If you do need to start the action from your popup, you can define a function in your background page, and invoke it using `chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(w){w.yourFunction();})`.

Also, keep in mind that in an extension you have the [chrome.windows](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html) and [chrome.tabs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html) APIs available.

Comment: Use [`chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-getBackgroundPage) for [event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html).

Comment: [`chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-getBackgroundPage) is asynchronous, because it the event page might not be loaded, and needs to be loaded first, so it's actually `chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(bgWindow) {bgWindow.yourFunction();});`

Comment: @RobW, ah, I took a quick look and didn't notice the focus on event pages and the signature change. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be delayed due to the browsers security framework. To open/close a window a user initiated event has to happen beforehand.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. My app closes a window without a user event. It isn't an extension, but still.

Comment: I can close the window if I set the close() interval less than 200ms. That is probably because it does not have enough time to send the first byte to the network.

Comment: @user2773389 That's probably because it's still in the "user initiated event" threshold. Network requests are fired almost instantly.

Comment: @nietonfir Whenever execution of code is queued in the event loop (e.g. using `setTimeout`), the "user-initiated event" state is lost. Your last comment is wrong. And the answer is partially correct: To close a window, no user-interaction is required. It is allowed when it was opened using `window.open()`.